# Python convert formatted string to list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string `"[u'foo']"` (Yes, it includes the square brackets and the `u''`). I have to convert that to a list which looks like `[u'foo']`.

`list("[u'foo']")` won't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify? What's the list supposed to contain?

Comment: Where does the string come from? That's not a very useful format to have; if you're generating it, consider using a better format.

Comment: I get it from GAE bulkloader bulk_download. It's a list property in the datastore. It get's downloaded and ends up looking like that in my csv file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[u'foo']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[u'foo']
```

[**documentation**](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 1):

```
eval("[u'foo']", {'__builtins__':[]}, {})
```

Comment: You know that passing empty dicts for `locals` and `globals` isn't enough to 'secure' `eval`, yes? This still gives an attacker basically full access to your system.

Comment: POC: `eval('__import__("os").getcwd()', {}, {})`, I edited my answer

Comment: @leoluk, that doesn't 'prove' anything. `eval("[x for x in type(type(1)).__bases__[0].__subclasses__() if x.__name__ == 'file'][0]('/etc/passwd').readline()", {}, {})` gives me the first line of `/etc/passwd` on my system.

Comment: @Aaron, cool... By the way, if I can't use literal_eval(), what would you suggest as a 'secure' eval?

Comment: @Albert, I would suggest modifying your desires so that you don't have to.

Comment: @Aaron: `eval('__import__("os").getcwd()', {}, {})` is no proof, it works fine. I just wanted to give an example that the first revision was insecure, and I fixed it.