# converting a string to a list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list

I need to convert a string, `'(2,3,4),(1,6,7)'` into a list of tuples `[(2,3,4),(1,6,7)]` in Python.
I was thinking to split up at every `','` and then use a for loop and append each tuple to an empty list. But I am not quite sure how to do it.
A hint, anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python convert formatted string to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622643/python-convert-formatted-string-to-list)

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> list(ast.literal_eval('(2,3,4),(1,6,7)'))
[(2, 3, 4), (1, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: +1 was about to post similar solution, but wrapping the string in [] and using eval. This looks much nicer.

Comment: I would like to do it without the ast.literal_eval.

Comment: because i haven't learnt about many of the built-in functions.. can you help?

Comment: @LinusSvendsson: Then you have just learned about a new one. :)  Well, anyway, when trying to provide a different solution, how would I know which function I am allowed to use, and which ones you would also reject?

Comment: I was thinking something like:
def f(string):
    t=string.split(',')
    L=[]
    for i in f:
        a=i.split(',')
        L.append(a)
    return L
But it is not working.. I am getting: [['(2,3,4)'],['(1,6,7)]]

Comment: @LinusSvendsson:  Sorry, I can't read your code.  And the alleged result isn't correct Python syntax.  Consider to edit your original question or ask a new one.

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work for me on Python 3.7.6. I basically get a list of characters.

Comment: @SkyWalker The code exactly as written in this answer works for me in Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 4):

Without ast or eval:

```
def convert(in_str):
    result = []
    current_tuple = []
    for token in in_str.split(","):
        number = int(token.replace("(","").replace(")", ""))
        current_tuple.append(number)
        if ")" in token:
           result.append(tuple(current_tuple))
           current_tuple = []
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

Without ast:

```
>>> list(eval('(2,3,4),(1,6,7)'))
    [(2, 3, 4), (1, 6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: soulcheck's solution, which meets the original poster's requirement to avoid ast.literal_eval:

```
def str2tupleList(s):
    return eval( "[%s]" % s )
```