# Transform string of coordinates stored in a tuple into list

Tags: python, data-processing

I have a string of coordinates stored in a sequence of tuples such as `'(522, 187) (522, 187) (522, 191) (523, 188) (522, 190)` (being stored in a deque first and then converted to string).

1. How is it possible to transform this entity into a list/deque of tuples? So that it would look like `[(522, 187), (522, 187), (522, 191), (523, 188), (522, 190)]`?

Simple splitting with split(',') doesn't work, as it then separates every coordinate due to ',' inside the tuple.

2. Is there any more convenient way of storing a list/deque of tuples in a **single** cell of .csv file? I need to store all coordinates received from every trial in an individual cell. Making two columns with _x and _y coordinates sometimes results into unequal length of these arrays.

Comment: I sense homework question, show your code.

Comment: By the way you can split then on **) (** and then parse them into list of coordinates, however I believe regex would be more suitable for your problem.

Comment: You'll need to massage the dupe's answer to work for you -- insert commas between tuples like this: `>>> ast.literal_eval('[{}]'.format('), ('.join(string.split(') ('))))  >>> [(522, 187), (522, 187), (522, 191), (523, 188), (522, 190)]` good luck!

Comment: @AKX is this really not a duplicate? I think it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting a string to a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490955/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: @Agent_Orange It's not homework, its a data processing procedure for a research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string with `) (`, then massage the individual tuples:

```
>>> [tuple(int(v) for v in a.strip("()").split(", ")) for a in s.split(') (')]
[(522, 187), (522, 187), (522, 191), (523, 188), (522, 190)]
```

Secondly, there are many ways. One would be to just store all coordinates as a single string, with the implicit knowledge they are X/Y pairs: `522,187,522,187,522,191,...`

Or you could store `[(522, 187), (522, 187), (522, 191)]` directly and use `ast.literal_eval()` to rehydrate it to a list-of-tuples.

Or, most preferably, you could use a data format that's not as *stringly typed* as CSV is, such as pickle files if you're working with Python alone, JSON if you need interchange, ...

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Will also try with json format, as I can see PsychoPy supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, use regex.

```
res = [tuple(e.replace(" ", "").split(",")) for e in  re.findall("[1-9]{3}, [1-9]{3}", string)]
```

This will be a list of tuples of strings.
To convert them into ints

```
list(map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), int(x[1])), res))
```

Havent gone through the optimization of this code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

tuples = '(522, 187) (522, 187) (522, 191) (523, 188) (522, 190)'

result = [literal_eval(f'({x})') for x in tuples.strip('()').split(') (')]
```

You can just memorize `tuples = str(result)` next time! You can retrieve it with `result = literal_eval(tuples)`

Comment: Eval is evil! :( (`ast.literal_eval()` would be the safer substitute.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
a = '(522, 187) (522, 187) (522, 191) (523, 188) (522, 190)'
res = list(eval(a.replace(', ',',').replace(' ',',')))
```

Output:

```
[(522, 187), (522, 187), (522, 191), (523, 188), (522, 190)]
```